# How to change specific permalink in wordpress site?

Tags: permalinks

I am not a coder, that's why I cannot change the URL from my site. I want to change the `?filter=latest` to `latest`  only.

Below is the code of `template-parts/content-filters.php`.

```
<?php if( !is_single() && !is_page() ) : ?>    
    <?php $paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 ); ?>
    <div class="filters">
        <a class="filter-title" href="#!"><?php echo wpst_get_filter_title(); ?></a>
        <div class="filters-list">
            <?php if( $paged === 0 ) : ?>   
                <a class="<?php echo wpst_selected_filter('latest'); ?>" href="<?php echo add_query_arg('filter', 'latest'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Newest', 'wpst'); ?></a>
                <a class="<?php echo wpst_selected_filter('popular'); ?>" href="<?php echo add_query_arg('filter', 'popular'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Best', 'wpst'); ?></a> 
                <a class="<?php echo wpst_selected_filter('most-viewed'); ?>" href="<?php echo add_query_arg('filter', 'most-viewed'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Most viewed', 'wpst'); ?></a>              
                <a class="<?php echo wpst_selected_filter('longest'); ?>" href="<?php echo add_query_arg('filter', 'longest'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Longest', 'wpst'); ?></a>
                <a class="<?php echo wpst_selected_filter('random'); ?>" href="<?php echo add_query_arg('filter', 'random'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Random', 'wpst'); ?></a> 
            <?php else : ?>
                <a class="<?php echo wpst_selected_filter('latest'); ?>" href="<?php echo wpst_get_nopaging_url(); ?>?filter=latest"><?php esc_html_e('Newest', 'wpst'); ?></a>
                <a class="<?php echo wpst_selected_filter('popular'); ?>" href="<?php echo wpst_get_nopaging_url(); ?>?filter=popular"><?php esc_html_e('Best', 'wpst'); ?></a>
                <a class="<?php echo wpst_selected_filter('most-viewed'); ?>" href="<?php echo wpst_get_nopaging_url(); ?>?filter=most-viewed"><?php esc_html_e('Most viewed', 'wpst'); ?></a>              
                <a class="<?php echo wpst_selected_filter('longest'); ?>" href="<?php echo wpst_get_nopaging_url(); ?>?filter=longest"><?php esc_html_e('Longest', 'wpst'); ?></a>
                <a class="<?php echo wpst_selected_filter('random'); ?>" href="<?php echo wpst_get_nopaging_url(); ?>?filter=random"><?php esc_html_e('Random', 'wpst'); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: All those `wpst_*` functions aren't part of WordPress core; they're added by either a plugin or a theme. You'll need to ask for support from the plugin's or the theme's support team.

Comment: Doing this will require code, and rewrite rules, but there's a very high chance that this isn't possible to answer with the information available. Where does `wpst_selected_filter` come from? Is this from a filter/facet plugin? 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here